# ¿Qué rango de años se considera como "mediados" de un siglo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, adverbios, locuciones, tiempo

Ayer se cumplieron 260 años del fallecimiento de [Miguel de Reina Ceballos](https://archivo.rae.es/index.php/reina-cevallos-miguel-de-1755), académico honorario de la RAE, motivo por el cual han desarrollado su ficha personal en la web de la entidad. Hay una cosa que me llama la atención de la ficha:

> Nació en Puebla de los Ángeles (México) a mediados del s. XVII. Murió el 30 de noviembre de 1760.

Vaya. Si nació a mediados del siglo XVII, eso quiere decir que nació alrededor del año 1650, y que por tanto pudo perfectamente vivir 110 años. Pero claro, decir "a mediados del siglo" es un poco vago. Lo mismo pudo ser en 1640 que en 1660, y en este caso habría vivido *solo* 100 años. Una cantidad aún nada desdeñable de años.

La expresión *[a mediados](https://dle.rae.es/mediado)* se define de manera un poco vaga en el DLE:

> 1. loc. adv. Hacia la mitad del tiempo que se indica o se sobrentiende.

¿Podemos definir esta expresión un poco mejor para este caso concreto? ¿Qué se entiende por "mediados de siglo"? Me cuesta creer que una persona viviera tanto tiempo en aquella época, aunque es perfectamente posible. Sin embargo, me inclino a pensar que en este caso con "a mediados" se refieren a una fecha indeterminada de la segunda mitad del siglo. ¿1670 sería también mediados del siglo XVII? ¿Y 1675? ¿Y 1680? ¿Dónde suele poner la gente el límite para decir que un año pertenece "a mediados" de un siglo o no?

Comment: En la ficha que enlazas aparece "Bachiller en la Universidad de México (1725)", o sea que lo de nacer a mediados del siglo anterior no parece tener mucha base. Finales del s.XVII más bien, no? Mediados yo consideraría los años correspondientes a las décadas 40-50-60, abriendo mucho el rango, en general me quedaría con la década del 50.

Comment: Va a ser difícil dar una respuesta con fuentes, pero yo normalmente divido los períodos en tres partes iguales: "principios", "mediados" y "finales". "Mediados de mes" es para mí del 10 al 20, y "mediados de siglo" sería aproximadamente de 33 a 67.

Answer (score 2):

Hacer cálculos con expresiones imprecisas es complicado, pero se hace.
Para este caso se podría definir lo que en lógica difusa se llama una función de pertenencia, como esta:
[image]

De hecho, la *[lógica difusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic)* (o *borrosa*) se inventó para operar con *[variables lingüísticas](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/linguistic-variable)*. Tal vez la RAE podría dedicarse a crear un diccionario de expresiones imprecisas con funciones de este tipo...